# how this solve this multivaluedictkeyerror in python 3.4?

Tags: python, django

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
@permission_classes([])
@authentication_classes([])
def does_account_exist_view(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        check_mail = request.GET['email'].lower()
        print(check_mail)
        data = {}
        try:
            account = Account.objects.get(email=check_mail)
            data['response'] = check_mail
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            data['response'] = "Account does not exist"
        return Response(data)
```

This code is running fine in python 3.8.5, but on my server python 3.4.3 why this telling error like this?

MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/account/check_if_account_exists
'email'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/.../.../check_if_account_exists
Django Version: 2.0.13
Python Executable: C:\p3.4_envs\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3

Comment: you might have 2 or more accounts with same email

Comment: It means your `request.GET` does not contain an `email` parameter. So there url is something like `/check_if_account_exists` instead of `/check_if_account_exists?email=blabla`

Answer (score 0):

Here you use **GET** method it look like dict but it standard dict. If you want rid of this error there is provided one method is **get** it call on dict and it accept to argument first is key of dict and second was default value if key not found in your **GET**

Here you can see if get method has email key it will return other default value

```
 check_mail = request.GET.get('email','email not found')
 print(check_mail)
```

make sure about email should have in url like http://127.0.0.1:8000/.../.../check_if_account_exists?email=admin@admin.com

so if you pass email it get passed email other wise default value email not found

[Get method of dict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-method-dictionaries-python/)

Hope you understand what I want to say might answer is satisfied to your question